# не открывается календарь

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Заказчик хочет нативный календарь,  но проблема в том, что он просто не открывается при нажатии
z-index не помог
в чем может быть проблема?

```
' <div class="container-fluid" style="min-width: 250px;">
                    <br/>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-inline">
                          <div class="form-group text-right">
                            <label>с&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                            <div class="input-group end_start" style="position:relative; z-index: 99997;">
                                <input
                                type="date"
                                v-model="filter_bg_end_date_start"
                              />
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <br/>
                        <div class="form-inline">
                          <div class="form-group text-right">
                            <label>по</label>
                            <div class="input-group end_end" style="position:relative; z-index: 99959;">
                               <input
                                type="date"
                                v-model="filter_bg_end_date_end"
                              />
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                  </div>
'
```

[image: каледарь]

Comment: в таком формате дату передаёте? new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10)

Comment: а при чем тут дата? я не понимаю

Comment: у меня именно календарь по кнопочке не открывается, а дата записывается, если вбивать вручную

Comment: @ДарьяСушкова вопрос схож с 'где я потеряла ключи' давайте угадаю может где то для input-а что то не то задано глянте в devtools ваш код вполне себе рабочий